# Show mutiple data info in doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show Multiple information in doughnut chart according to below image
[image]

Anybody please tell how can i do it. here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qpem8fzv/1/

i want to show total data in 100% and other data in parts. please see attached image for detail info.

```js
var doughnutData = [{
    value: 100,
    color: "#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red",
  },
  {
    value: 25,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green"
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
  }

];

var ctx1 = $("#d1").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
  percentageInnerCutout: 90
});
```

```css
#w {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#d1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#d1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="w">
  <canvas id="d1" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: are you open to use like highcharts?

Comment: I am using Chart JS

Answer (score 0):

The chart is going to use the total value of all segments as 100%. So, the easiest way to achieve what you want, is to exclude your 100% value from the segments, and include a segment which serves as the remainder up to 100%.

So... in your example, remove the first segment from `doughnutData`, and add one at the end, like so:

```
    var doughnutData = [
        {
            value: 25,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
            value:25,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red",
        },
    ];
```

The added segment will have a value of 100 - (value of first segment: 25) - (value of second segment: 50) = 25. And then you just add another label for the 100% segment.

EDIT: 
jsfiddle for the above: https://jsfiddle.net/vcdruo2f/2/

While this does mean that the Hover Tooltip is incorrect for the "total" segment, it is logically correct in order to display 100%, which is what you want in a pie/doughnut chart.

Also look at: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Comment: but on hover it will show deduct value not total amount

Comment: @zero Yes, that is true... An alternative would be: https://jsfiddle.net/vuwr1c4n/3/ but it has a different issue with the labels.